# Как вывести значения из базы в чекбоксы?

Tags: php, laravel

есть модель интересов Interest = id | title

и модель UserInterest = id | user_id | interest_id

как при выводе отмечать пользовательские значения?

```
@forelse($user_interests as $interest)
        <li>
               <div class="checkbox-input">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="interest_{{$interest->id}}" name="interests[]" value="{{$interest->id}}">
                        <label for="interest_{{$interest->id}}">{{$interest->title}}</label>
                </div>
        </li>
        @empty
 @endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$interests = Interest::all();

$user_interests = UserInterest::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('interest_id')->toArray();
```

Blade

```
@forelse($interests as $interest)
        <li>
               <div class="checkbox-input">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="interest_{{$interest->id}}" name="interests[]" value="{{$interest->id}}" {{ in_array($interest->id, $user_interests) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                        <label for="interest_{{$interest->id}}">{{$interest->title}}</label>
                </div>
        </li>
 @endforelse
```